# How to copy/paste the formulas of Row 2 into lower rows IF Column A isn't empty?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet where the cells in Column A auto-populate based on user input. Row 1 is the Headers. Row 2 is fully setup from B:JG with formulas as an example. I would like to have a button that runs a script to check Column A of each row, starting with 3, to see if its empty. If Column A is not empty, it should copy the FORMULAS from B2:JG2 and paste them into Columns B:JG on each row. If Column A is empty, I want it to leave the other columns blank.

I'm just diving into VBA, so any help with a script to accomplish is appreciated.

Example: Rows 3-110 have data in Column A, so B2:JG2 FORMULAS get copied into their B:JG columns. All rows after 110 get nothing because Column A is empty.

The button is on a sheet called "HexBox" and the sheet I need to update is "HexClean".

The user enters some info on the "HexBox" sheet and A:A is auto-populated based on their answers. So there could be 10 or 1000 rows in A:A with values and the rest up to 5000 will be "" if not applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach simply

1. Copies the formulas from 2nd row down to the last used row as determined by `Column A` (**one operation**). Note that this step is indifferent of blanks in your column. That is handled in the following 2 steps
2. Loops through `Column A` and gather up instances of blank rows by adding them to a `Union` (collection of cells) (**0 operations**)
3. Clears the contents of the `Union` that is built in step 2 (**one operation**)

---

This is a more effecient way to go. Copying & pasting the formulas inside your loop one row at a time will lead to a lot of spread sheet operations. **This method has a max of 2 operations**

```
Sub HexSub()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HexClean")

Dim LR As Long, i As Long, ClearMe As Range
LR = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

ws.Range("B2:JG2").Copy
ws.Range(ws.Cells(3, "B"), ws.Cells(LR, "JG")).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas

For i = 3 To LR
    If ws.Range("A" & i) = "" Then
        If Not ClearMe Is Nothing Then
            Set ClearMe = Union(ClearMe, ws.Range("A" & i))
        Else
            Set ClearMe = ws.Range("A" & i)
        End If
    End If
Next i

If Not ClearMe Is Nothing Then ClearMe.EntireRow.ClearContents

End Sub
```

*If your range will never have blanks followed by more values, then you can just get rid of the loop and everything below it*

Comment: Tested on 2,000 rows - Much faster than my old trudge through them all method ...

Answer (score 0):

If the non-blank cells in column A are typed values then SpecialCells should be able to find them quickly.

```
Sub populateBelow()

    Dim frng As Range

    With Worksheets("sheet3")

        Set frng = .Range(.Cells(2, "B"), .Cells(2, "JG"))

        With .Range(.Cells(3, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))

            With .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues + xlNumbers)

                frng.Copy Destination:=.Offset(0, 1)

            End With

        End With

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: It returned a "no cells were found" error. I should add that the button is on a different sheet called "HexBox" and the sheet I need to work with is called "HexClean". I changed "Sheet3" to "HexClean" in your code and got the error.

Comment: Where do the values in HexClean!A:A come from?

Comment: The user enters some info on the "HexBox" sheet and A:A is auto-populated based on their answers. So there could be 10 or 1000 rows in A:A with values and the rest up to 5000 will be "" if not applicable.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub CopyToMany()
    Dim xRow As Range, aCel As Range

    For Each xRow In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows
       If xRow.Row > 2 Then
          Set aCel = xRow.Cells(1, 1)
          If aCel.Value <> "" Then
             ActiveSheet.Range("B2:JG2").Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("B" & xRow.Row & ":JG" & xRow.Row)
          End If
       End If
    Next xRow
End Sub
```

Comment: It returned an error. "Copy method failed" and highlighted this line ```ActiveSheet.Range("B2:JG2").Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("B" & xRow.Row & ":JG" & xRow.Row)```

Comment: It would have to be amended for your sheet names which you clarified just before I logged off for the night - worked for me - but you cannot use activesheet