# How can I clear the contents of (only) hidden cells in Excel (and not delete them)?

Tags: excel, vba

(context:  I know a lot about writing complex formulas in Excel, but have very basic understanding of VBA.  I am amazed that I couldn't find a solution to the problem I am trying to solve on my own which makes we wonder if there is something in Excel that makes it impossible to do).  I would like to imagine many others would find this as beneficial as I will because I'm sure lots of people get bloated Excel templates.

I have an Excel template with a variety of cells across a variety of worksheets with pre-populated formulas that update based on dumping a changing set of data into one worksheet.  I use the template for different 'projects' that do not all require the use of all the cells pre-populated with formulas.  So, once new data is imported, certain unused rows and columns are hidden (either manually or with a VBA macro) because they are not needed.

I would like to find a way to clear the contents (i.e. the formulas) in all the hidden cells to reduce the overall file size.  My files quickly get over 100 MB, but perhaps 80% of the cells that contain formulas are not used for any particular project and could be cleared.

I'm not a VBA expert, but I've searched for this through Google, thinking it would be an easy snippet of VBA to find, but after literally hours of going deep into Google search result ranks, I haven't found a single good result that sent me in the direction of a solution.

There is a lot of content about how to use VBA to *delete* hidden rows or columns, but I can't do that with my workbook (I need the the rows and columns to remain for other formulas and formats to work).  I just want to remove the unused formulas in hidden cells.

I understand that I can use the following to clear contents and/or clear formats

```
Sheets("Test").Range("A1:C3").ClearContents
Sheets("Test").Range("A1:C3").ClearFormats
```

and I use this line to hide cells:

```
Range.Hidden = True
```

So, how can I get the range for the `ClearContents` function be be defined as hidden cells (or to have it only act on hidden cells)?  And, how can this be done efficiently...I've learned that running a loop can take a great deal of time as it progressing through rows or columns to perform a task.

I would like to have a solution that allows for this process:

1. Import new data
2. Hide unneeded rows and columns
3. Push a macro button to clear all formulas from all cells within a certain `Range(A3:TY53)` across all worksheets

Any help or pointing me to an existing solution I wasn't able to find on my own would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try the other way around, have the template only with the first Row of formulas. When the second workbook with the data is used, get the Last Row and FillDown the formulas to that row on the template.

Comment: As Ricardo A suggests .... and the accepted answer in this post provides a solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55961909/how-to-copy-paste-the-formulas-of-row-2-into-lower-rows-if-column-a-isnt-empty/55962037#55962037

Comment: Ricardo and Knee - thanks for the replies and thinking about a different approach.  I appreciate it.  However, I couldn't use your solution because I also need to be able to sort the columns in each worksheet once populated, which means each row of formulas requires absolute references that remain connected with the same cells after sorting has changed their order (i.e. if I copy the row down, every row would point at the same set of cells as the first row).  I do really appreciate the idea, which would have worked if not for the need to sort...unless you know a way to also work around that?

Answer (score 2):

To clear the contents of hidden cells:

```
Sub KlearHidden()
    Dim r As Range

    For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If r.EntireRow.Hidden Or r.EntireColumn.Hidden Then
            r.Clear
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Gary's Student - this is awesome (magic in just a few lines).  One question...this seems set up to only run on active worksheets.  Is there a way to have it work across the entire workbook?  I hoped to have a button in one worksheet that I click to clear hidden cells for the entire workbook.  Or, you may have a better idea.  I found this code that is supposed to loop through and activate all worksheets, but I've used loops before that can take a long time to run.  Regardless of your reply, know that I am very appreciative and still find a way to pay this forward.

Comment: Sub loop_through_all_worksheets()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim starting_ws As Worksheet
Set starting_ws = ActiveSheet 'remember which worksheet is active in the beginning

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Activate
    'do whatever you need
    ws.Cells(1, 1) = 1 'this sets cell A1 of each sheet to "1"
Next

starting_ws.Activate 'activate the worksheet that was originally active

End Sub